# How to create content in apache sling using java program

Tags: sling, jackrabbit

I am new to apache sling i want to create content(node) using java program and that to be stored in jackrabbit

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is too broad, you need to show that you have made some effort yourself first. You can read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details

Answer (score 1):

Every HTTP request targeting Sling (`localhost:8080/path/to/my/resource`) providing basic authentication will do just fine. In that sense Sling is completely client agnostic and you are free to choose language and library (i.e. Apache Commons) of your choice.